# Is SQLLITE3 installation only a single file?

Tags: sqlite, installation

I downloaded sqlite-shell-win32-x86-3071000 and sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3071000 from the lin: http://www.sqlite.org/download.html. The exe is present under the sqlite-shell-win32-x86-3071000 folder. On double-clicking the exe, only a command prompt opened, no installation happened. Please inform how to install it.

Please help

Comment: there is sqlite in android, right? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Comment: yes there is sqlite in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlite3 is just an executable, don't doubt it!!

Comment: Ok i solved the problem. I have learnt how to use the adb shell when the emulator is running to check  the table contents. Thanks